# CSS Half circle progress in IE7+

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I made this example with border-radius & linear-gradient: [Code-Pen](http://codepen.io/KAYNguyen/pen/ligrG/)

How can I make this work in IE 7+

PS: Afterwards I've tried CSS3pie

---

[image: http://imageshack.com/a/img703/8333/yp5m.png]

Comment: Not an answer, but just some grumpy advice: Don't develop for a browser that is bound to die after decades of horrible implementations and lack of features. :(

Comment: Looks like your code works in IE10+, just forget older IEs...

Comment: `SVG` **d3.js** or **raphael js** if you can get done... good luck

Comment: The problem of the IE7 or IE8 compatibility isn't always an option. Sometimes it's a requirement, when IE7 finally died, I think I'm going to make a huge party...